# Why the button element is not working when used inside foreach loop inside view in a laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel

I need a graph inside a card, with records from the database.

Each card contains a `button` element, which **onclick**, **updates the value for the particular ID of the card.** . *The value will be triggered through the event*.

**Controller:**

```
class SampleController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
    {

        $users=User::all();

        return view('progress', ['users'=> $users]);

    }
```

```
@foreach($users as $user)
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-title">
                        <div class="caption">
                             {{ $user['name'] }}
                        </div>

                        <div class="actions">
                            <div class="btn">
                                <button id="ref">Refresh</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body" id="{{ $user['id'] }}">
                        <center>
                            <div style=" display:inline; width: 200px; height: 200px;">
                                <input
                                    class="graph"
                                    data-max="{{ $user['goal'] }}"
                                    value= ""
                                />
                            </div>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
```

**Script:**:

```
 var pusher = new Pusher('xxxxxxx', {
        cluster: 'ap3',
        encrypted: true
      });


   // Subscribe to the channel we specified in our Laravel Event
        var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
              channel.bind('App\\Events\\myEvent', function(data){
              target = data.id;
              value = data.value;
        //Refresh button

         $('#ref').click(function(){
             $.ajax({url: '/api/getId/' + target,
                 success: function(){
                 alert('THe UI is updated' + value);
             $(target).block({
                        message: 'processing',
                        timeout: 20000,

                    });
             $(target).unblock();
              
                }
            });
         });
```

When I pass the value through tinker like the below,

```
event(new App\Events\myEvent('3',40));
```

I could see the particular `Id(3)` is updated with the value `40`.

*The purpose of refresh is ,the card should be blocked for 20seconds, Meanwhile If I pass the value through Event for the particularId, It unblocks the card and updates the card with the new value.*

*The problem is ,If I have 10 cards, only the refresh button in the first card works, the refresh button in the remaining cards doesn't work.*

How can I make the refresh button work in all the cards?

Could anyone please help?
Many thanks.

Comment: id should be unique for each element .try adding class  name and change  $(document).on('click','.classname',function(){

Comment: @John Lobo, It works! But, If I change the Value for the Card with ID:1, It updates the value for the Id:1 after the refresh button is clicked. `But, If i Press the refresh button for the ID:2, It takes the same Value which I  have given to the ID: 1 `. That should not be the case, If I there is `NAN` in the value, Then after clicking the refresh button `NAN` should be the value after clicking the Refresh button. How could I do that? Could you please help?

Comment: because you are accessing value out of onclick target = data.id;
              value = data.value; . so better set id to button like this   <button id="ref" data-id-"{{ $user['id'] }}">Refresh</button> so you can get in inside onclick $(this).attr("data-id")

Comment: @John Lobo, Sorry I didnt get you. If I set, <button id="ref" data-id-"{{ $user['id'] }}">Refresh</button>  then how to pass data-id in the script below? ,          $(document).on('click','.ref ',function(){
             $.ajax({url: '/api/getId/' + target,
                 success: function(){
                 alert('THe UI is blocked' + target);
                 var tar =  document.getElementById(target);                      
                 $(tar).block({
                        message: 'processing',
                        timeout: 20000 });
                }   });

Comment: <button id="ref" class="ref" data-id-"{{ $user['id'] }}">Refresh</button>
 
  $('.ref').click(function(){
  var target=$(this).attr('data-id')
             $.ajax({url: '/api/getId/' + target,
                 success: function(){
                 alert('THe UI is updated' + value);
             $(target).block({
                        message: 'processing',
                        timeout: 20000,

                    });
             $(target).unblock();
              
                }
            });
         });

Comment: @John Lobo, Can we declare both `id` and `class` attribute together  in the button element?

Comment: yes we can .there is no restriction ,class can have multiple names but id should one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233478/discussion-between-kovidak-and-john-lobo).